# Convert to timestamp from char in SQL loader

Tags: oracle, timestamp, sql-loader

I have in a file (cvs) a column with the following `2015051308384828` and i want to convert this char in my sql loader to timestamp and inser the value in database.

CREATION OF TABLE :

```
CREATE_TABLE "MY_TABLE"
(
 ...
 ,DATE_MAJ TIMESTAMP
 ...
)
```

I do this in my sql loader :

```
DATE_MAJ TIMESTAMP "yyyymmddhh24missff"
```

I have the following error : `ORA-01821 It is not a valid month`

Help

Comment: What is the data type of your DATE_MAJ column?

Comment: In database, the column DATE_MAJ is TIMESTAMP

Comment: Works fine for me in 11.2.0.3. Can you add your version, and perhaps more of the control and log files? Partly to make sure you don't have any other date fields and you're thinking the error is on the wrong one, partly in case there's something else affecting its behaviour...

Comment: Works fine for me on `12.1.0.2`

Comment: Works fine for me in 10.2.0.5 too (with timestamp or timestamp(3) from the comment you've now deleted, which also said you were using 10g). Showing the control file, data file and log file might explain where the problem is, at is doesn't seem to be with what you've shown. Otherwise don't think we can help, if we can't reproduce what you're seeing.